# Allow "-" (hyphen) before @ symbol for email validation

Tags: regex, email-validation

I am working on email validation for a asp.net server control.

Below are the sample emails system should allow -

```
test@domain.com
test@domain.subdomain.com
v-test@domain.com
v-test@domain.subdomain.com
```

Can anyone please tell me how to write a regular expression for the above email validation.

Here is my code working correctly for simple emails like `test@domain.com` etc

```
var emailPat = /^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/

var EmailmatchArray = UserEmail.match(emailPat);

if (EmailmatchArray == null) {
document.getElementById('<%=lblEmailErrorCtrl.ClientID%>').innerText = "Invalid email address";
return false;

}
```

Comment: A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+validation+regex&oq=email+validation+regex&aqs=chrome..69i57.263j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) for "email validation regex" shows some things that might come in handy, namely [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this will not magically validate all valid emails - that task is nearly impossible. To fix your situation though, try:

```
var emailPat = /^(\".\"|[-A-Za-z]\w)@([\d{1,3}(.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/
```